# Smooth transition between CSS animation when updating animation parameters

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations

I have an animated HTML element (`box`) as follow:

```
<div id="box"></div>
```

The box is initially animated to 200 pixels to the right with a duration of 4 seconds.

```
.anim {
    animation-name: anim;
    animation-duration: 4s; 
    animation-timing-function: linear; /* cubic-bezier(0.1, -0.6, 0.2, 0); */
}

@keyframes anim {
    0% { left: var(--xs); }
    100% { left: var(--xe); }
}
```

Here the JavaScript that starts the animation:

```
var box = document.getElementById('box');

box.style.setProperty('--xs', '0px');
box.style.setProperty('--xe', '200px');
box.classList.add('anim');
```

After one second, the final position is updated to 400 pixels:

```
setTimeout(() => {
    box.style.setProperty('--xe', '400px');
},1000)
```

Of course, when the final position is updated, the box jumps from one position to the other. Is there a way to get a smooth transition to avoid the "teletransportation" effect?

Here is the JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Imabot/53hLe2zq/

Answer (score 1):

Change its `animation-duration` to 8 seconds:

```js
setTimeout(() => {
    box.style.setProperty('--xe', '400px');
    box.style.animationDuration = '8s';
}, 1000);
```

Originally, the box was meant to move 200 pixels in 4 seconds; by a simple division we know that its speed is set to 50px/s.

```
┌──────┐
│ 50/s │                            (4s away)
└──────┘
|-------------------|-------------------|
0                  100                 200
```

After one second, when the callback is fired, the length suddenly doubles to 400; this cause the box's speed to increase to 100px/s. However, since it is already 50px from the original position, it must "teleport" to 100px to be able to travel the rest in 3 seconds.

```
          ┌──────┐
          │ 50/s │                                                          (3s away)
          └──────┘
|---------|---------|-------------------|-------------------|-------------------|
0         50       100                 200                 300                 400

                    ┌──────┐
                    │ 100/s│                                                (3s away)
                    └──────┘
|---------|---------|-------------------|-------------------|-------------------|
0         50       100                 200                 300                 400
```

So, to prevent it from teleporting we need to give it more time, making its speed remain consistent. Again, we need math:

```
( 400  -  50 ) /  50   = 7    (seconds)
To_be_traveled / Speed = Time
```

Add it to 1 second we already used to travel the first 50 pixels and we have the final answer: 8 seconds.

And that's all there is to it! Should your actual input changes, you can simply convert the formula above to a function. Note that this won't work with any `animation-timing-function` other than `linear`.

Try it:

```js
var box = document.getElementById('box');

box.style.setProperty('--xs', '0px');
box.style.setProperty('--xe', '200px');
box.classList.add('anim');

setTimeout(() => {
    box.style.setProperty('--xe', '400px');
    box.style.animationDuration = '8s';
}, 1000)
```

```css
#box {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: red;
    border-radius: 15px;
    position: relative; 
}

.anim {
    animation-name: anim;
    animation-duration: 4s; 
    animation-timing-function: linear;
}

@keyframes anim {
    0% { left: var(--xs); }
    100% { left: var(--xe); }
}
```

```html
<div id="box"></div>
```

Comment: Awesome, thx. Unfortunately in my app the timing function is not linear...

Answer (score -1):

you can use the following code to create a smooth transition between the two states:

CSS:

```
#box {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
  left: 0px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  transition: left 4s ease-out;
}

#box.animate {
   left: 400px;
}

@keyframes anim {
    0% { left: var(--xs); }
    100% { left: var(--xe); }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="box"></div>
```

JS:

```
var box = document.getElementById('box');
setTimeout(function() { box.classList.add('animate'); }, 1000);
```

This will create a smooth transition between the two states, with a duration of 4s.

Here is the JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1fuq9ebL/

Comment: Thx for the answer, but it does not work: https://jsfiddle.net/Imabot/53hLe2zq/5/

Comment: @Fifi look at the new code

Comment: @Fifi check the code it works.

Comment: Thx, but this is no longer the answer to my initial question